# Flash not working on redirect during unittest testing

Tags: python, flask, python-unittest

I have an endpoint that does some logic and a `flash()`and then redirects to another endpoint, which adds another flash and displays both flashed messages. When I test the endpoint in my browser, I get both messages. However, when I do my unittest, the first flash doesn't show up.

```
@bp.route('/signup/', methods=['POST'])
def signup():
    form = SignupForm(prefix='signup')
    next_url = url_for('.home')

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # do stuff like add to waiting list
        person = persons.new()
        form.populate_obj(person)
        person = persons.save(person)
        flash(Markup(u'Thanks for signing up!'), 'success')
    return redirect(next_url)

@bp.route('/')
def home():
    flash('This is home', 'info')
    return render_template('home.html')


class PageTests(MTestCase):

    def test_signup(self):
     r = self.post('/signup/',
        data={
            'signup-email': 'test1@test.com',
        })
        person = persons.find(email='test1@test.com').first()
        self.assertIsNotNone(person)
        self.assertIn('Thanks for signing up', r.data)
```

I'm guessing that during the redirect the flash queue is lost, but I'm not entirely sure how or why.

Answer (score 0):

Add `follow_redirects=True` argument because login page redirects.

```
r = self.post(
    '/signup/',
    data={
        'signup-email': 'test1@test.com',
    },
    follow_redirects=True  # <----
)
```

See [Logging in and out - Testing Flask Application](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/testing/#logging-in-and-out).